# Getting "Cannot find index to verify that join fields will be unique" on aggregation pipeline using _id

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm building an aggregation pipeline to merge data from 2 collections on the same DDBB. Source collection is TmpPersoOptins, destination is RecipientAggregate. Data on source looks like:

```
{
  "_id": 61231246,
  "PersoOptins": 1
}
```

Data on destination looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(1)
    "Member" : {
        "AccountState" : NumberInt(1),
        "BirthDate" : ISODate("1986-06-05T22:00:00.000+0000"),
        "CreationDate" : ISODate("2001-01-30T23:56:00.000+0000"),
        "Culture" : "fr-FR",
        "Email" : "test@hotmail.com",
        "FirstName" : "Lorem",
        "Gender" : NumberInt(1),
        "GodFatherId" : NumberLong(657),
        "LastName" : "Ipsum",
        "ModificationDate" : ISODate("2022-04-20T15:44:00.000+0000"),
        "SchemaVersion" : NumberInt(1),
        "SiteId" : NumberInt(1)
    }
}
```

I want to add source property "PersoOptins" to all records on destination that doesn't contain it. I'm merging on _id field. This is my pipeline:

```
[
  {
    $fill:
      {
        output: {
          OptinPerso: {
            value: 0,
          },
        },
      },
  },
  {
    $lookup:
      {
        from: "RecipientAggregate",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              "Member.OptinPerso": {
                $exists: false,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        as: "Result",
      },
  },
  {
    $unwind:
      {
        path: "$Result",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false,
      },
  },
  {
    $project:
      {
        _id: 1,
        "Member.OptinPerso": "$PersoOptins",
      },
  },
  {
    $merge:
      {
        into: "RecipientAggregate",
        on: "_id",
        whenMatched: "merge",
      },
  },
]
```

However, I'm getting error `Cannot find index to verify that join fields will be unique` on the merge stage, and I can't find the problem, as _id field used for joining is the PK on both collections. The only difference is that source _id field is a regular index, while _id on destination is a clustered one. Any hint?

Comment: I have modified source _id field to be a clustered index too, but still getting the same error...

Comment: So `RecipientAggregate` is a clustered collection (as opposed to a standard collection or a view)?

Comment: @user20042973 They both are. I changed source "TmpPersoOptins" to be also clustered, traying to find if the issue was different kind of indexes. Also, both unique. But error still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue, posting here just for the records. Merge pipeline step on MongoDB 6.0.2 is not working with a clustered index. I had to add a new regular unique index for it to work.